# SQL Server - Calculated column Sum from different table

Tags: sql, sum, calculated-columns

I have two tables (`Items` and `Item_Types`), and I want to do something like the following as a formula in a calculated column in the `Item_Types` table:

```
SELECT SUM(Items.Qty_In_Stock) FROM Items WHERE Items.Item_Type = Item_Types.ID
```

But Management Studio isn't liking it.

How can I do this? Or have I just got my syntax wrong? I'm not great with SQL.

Thanks

EDIT: I think I need to be more specific.

One `ItemType` can have many `Items`.

Each `Item` has a `Qty_In_Stock` field.

I want to get a sum of all `Qty_In_Stock` fields *where `Items.Item_Type` = `Item_Types.ID`* - not just a sum of the entire column.

Cheers

Comment: I assumed that is what you were trying to do. Read my answer below to see if my entire assumption was correct. Before anybody downvotes the other answers, be aware that the OP's stated requirements changed and they were just giving answers that were suitable to the original requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to show the available qty for each item type:
I would recommend creating a view that shows this information:
You will need to "GROUP BY" the item type.

```
CREATE VIEW Item_Types_Qty_In_Stock
AS

SELECT it.ID, SUM(i.Qty_In_Stock) AS QtyInStock FROM Items i
INNER JOIN Item_Types it ON i.Item_Type = it.ID 
GROUP BY it.ID
GO
```

Once you have created the view, you can query it as if it were a table:

```
SELECT * FROM Item_Types_Qty_In_Stock
```

Comment: Forgot to add, there was an 'AS' statement missing from the above code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no join for the Item_types table. Put a join and you should be OK.

```
SELECT SUM(Items.Qty_In_Stock) from Items INNER JOIN Item_Types ON Items.Item_Type = Item_Types.ID GROUP BY Items.Item_Type
```

Comment: Yeah I realised the join thing, but this still doesn't work when entered as a calculated column - are joins allowed in calculated columns?

Comment: Yes they are. You also will need to have a group by to make the query complete.

Comment: As with John's answer below, I still get "Error validating the formula for column 'Stock_Qty'" when I try to enter this into a computed column specification in Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

Below will return the sum of Qty_In_Stock for all items with at least one Item_type record.

```
SELECT 
   SUM(i.Qty_In_Stock)
FROM Items i
INNER JOIN Item_types it on i.Item_Type = it.ID
```

You may want to use a left join if every item does not have at least one Item_type record  Example:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(i.Qty_In_Stock)
FROM Items i
LEFT JOIN Item_types it on i.Item_Type = it.ID
```

**Edited**

Perhaps this is what you want.  This will return an individual sum of Items(qty_in_stock) for each Item_type ID

```
SELECT 
   it.Id,
   SUM(i.Qty_In_Stock)
FROM Items i
INNER JOIN Item_types it on i.Item_Type = it.ID 
GROUP BY it.Id
```

Comment: I still get "Error validating the formula for column 'Stock_Qty'" when I try to enter this into a computed column specification in Management Studio...

Answer (score 0):

A computed column is computed from an expression that can use other columns **in the same table**. The expression can be a noncomputed column name, constant, function, and any combination of these connected by one or more operators. **The expression cannot be a subquery**.